# GridBagLayout is not aligns as expected with JPanel in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I would like to create resizeable frame using `gridbaglayout` (consist of 6 `JPanels`) + using right to left orientation. Its working well until 4th `JPanel` after adding 5th and 6th `JPanel` expected alignment is not coming.

Please guide me to get expected alignment.

**expected output**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameGUI {
public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane){
    pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

    JPanel blackPanel,bluePanel,greenPanel,orangePanel,pinkPanel,redPanel;

    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c=new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,660));

    //################################################## BLACK JPanel
    blackPanel=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    c.weightx=0.8;
    c.weighty=0.3;
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.gridwidth=2;
    c.gridheight=1;
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=0;

    blackPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
    pane.add(blackPanel, c);

    //################################################## BLUE JPanel
    bluePanel=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx=0.8;
    c.weighty=0.1;
    c.gridheight=1;
    c.gridwidth=2;
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=1;

    bluePanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    pane.add(bluePanel, c);

    //################################################## GREEN JPanel
    greenPanel=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx=0.2;
    c.weighty=0.4;
    c.gridwidth=1;
    c.gridheight=2;
    c.gridx=2;
    c.gridy=0;

    greenPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
    pane.add(greenPanel, c);

    //################################################## ORANGE JPanel
    orangePanel=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx=1.0;
    c.weighty=0.2;
    c.gridheight=1;
    c.gridwidth=3;
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=2;

    orangePanel.setBackground(Color.orange);
    pane.add(orangePanel, c);

    //################################################## PINK JPanel
    pinkPanel=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx=0.2;
    c.weighty=0.4;
    c.gridheight=1;
    c.gridwidth=1;
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=3;

    pinkPanel.setBackground(Color.pink);
    pane.add(pinkPanel, c);

    //################################################## RED JPanel
    redPanel=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx=0.8;
    c.weighty=0.4;
    c.gridheight=1;
    c.gridwidth=2;
    c.gridx=1;
    c.gridy=3;

    redPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    pane.add(redPanel, c);

}

 private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayoutDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `please guide me to get expected alignment.` - what is the "expected alignment"?

Comment: We can't read your mind, so we don't know what you expect. Care to tell us?

Comment: @user3510723 what is the expected output? Create a sipmle picture with paint and post it for better understanding of your expected output

Comment: Provide ASCII art (or as @Arijit suggested - an image with a simple drawing) of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Comment: I have tried to insert image but its not allowing because of less privilege or something..